# Java + HTML, How to display list?

Tags: java, html, list, netbeans

I am using Netbeans to display a simple list,

it is working with "list of string",

but cannot success with "list of 'customer'"

I want to display the name, age of the customer

Here is my code:

```
public class Customer {
            private String name;
            public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }
            public String getName(){ return name;}
            public Customer(String name){
                this.name = name;
            }
        }
```

Customers object

```
public final SimpleListProperty<Customer> Customers = new SimpleListProperty<>(this, "Customers", FXCollections.observableArrayList());
```

Add a customer

```
Customer customer = new Customer('test');
Customers.getValue().add(customer);
```

Interface

```
<div class="row">
     <ul class="col s12 collection" data-bind="foreach: Customers">
          <li class="collection-item">
               <span data-bind="text: $data.name"></span>
          </li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

I tried all the following

```
<span data-bind="text: $data"></span>

<span data-bind="text: $data.name"></span>

<span data-bind="text: $name"></span>
```

Nothing work, only empty list appears.
But when I changed the list to (list of simple string) it works fine.

I also tried "private String name;" and "public String name;"

Any help, please

Comment: overwrite the `toString()` method in your `Customer` class

Comment: Thanks AKSW, this is good idea, but I want to format the output using customer.name, customer.age .... and so on. Not only one string return.

Comment: When I used the override function "$data.toString()", it works. But if I used my own function "$data.getName()", it give me silient error "java nullpointerexception". Any help?

Comment: The error come in IE Console "java.lang.NullPointerException: TypeError: a is null"

Comment: There is no `data-bind` built into Java not HTML. Are you trying to use some data binding library? If so, name it. And add a tag if one exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is in case some one face the same problem,

I did not fix it, but I find work around.

Based on "AKSW" suggestion, I used .toString() override.

The problem now is how to show Name, Age, ..... separately,

I used html binding instead ot text:

```
<div data-bind="html: $data.toString()"></div>
```

Then I format the "toString()" in HTML as I want like

```
@Override
public String toString()
{
    return "<span>Name</span><span>Age</span>";
}
```

Now I can get the result which I need.

Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [Knockout](https://knockoutjs.com/index.html), then you should do it like the [**example**](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html) in the [**documentation**](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/introduction.html):

> ```html
> <tbody data-bind="foreach: people">
>     <tr>
>         <td data-bind="text: firstName"></td>
>         <td data-bind="text: lastName"></td>
>     </tr>
> </tbody>
> ```

Which means:

```html
<div class="row">
     <ul class="col s12 collection" data-bind="foreach: Customers">
          <li class="collection-item">
               <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
          </li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Andreas, I am using "FXBeanInfo.Provider". I already tried "<span data-bind="text: name"></span>" but also empty string. If my list is a simple "String" objects, it appears in the list when I use "<span data-bind="text: $data"></span>". But if my list is 'Customer', it show "Customer@7cc1c536", I tried to add '.name' but give me empty text.

Comment: I am adding and controlling my list from my java class, not using "javascript"

Comment: @Flyinglight Are you sure the `name` field is not null or empty string? Try implementing `toString()` on `Customer`, so you don't get text like `Customer@7cc1c536` when use just use `$data`.